# Redirect to all traffic to SSL pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I am attempting to redirect all traffic to Secure pages.  I attempted an to try using either a PHP redirect, and an htaccess redirect.  They worked, BUT, the problem is I get the following error:

"You attempted to reach domain.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as www.domain.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of domain.com."

We are the same domain.  How do I go fixing the problem of the SSL certificate working for one domain but no the other domain?

Comment: Show your existing .htaccess rule.

Comment: Redirect to `https://www.domain.com` instead of `https://domain.com`. Don't bother trying to run the same site on two different hostnames.

Comment: Here is what I am using:

`#SSL Redirect`
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`
`RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because the SSL cert that you have seems to be for `www.domain.com` and *not* `domain.com`. You're not going to be able to avoid this if people attempt to go to `https://domain.com` but you can canonicalize this using the same rule for redirecting to SSL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

See also: http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/certificate-name-mismatch-error.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  What does canonicalize mean? I don't quite understand the concept.  ELI5.

Comment: @MethodWWW it means you only want traffic going to `www.domain.com` and not anything else (e.g. `domain.com`)

Comment: I don't exactly know why or how, but this method appears to work.  Much thanks:).